# adding a transparent upper layer to a div containing text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a text inside a `div` I want add a transparent image over this `div`.

On click on the image the content of the back `div` show with `div` changing width to show the whole text with a scroll bar. Please anyone has a solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

this is the text div code with a 400px :

```
 <div class="about-style">
                        <h2 class="about-header">About</h2><br><br>
                        <p class="about-text-style">
                            London, England’s capital, 
                            set on the River Thames, is a 21st-century city with history stretching back to Roman times. At its centre stand the imposing Houses of Parliament, the iconic ‘Big Ben’ clock tower and Westminster Abbey, site of British monarch coronations. 
                            Across the Thames, the London Eye observation wheel provides panoramic views of the South Bank cultural complex, and the entire city. times. At its centre stand the imposing Houses of Parliament, the iconic ‘Big Ben’ clock tower and Westminster Abbey, site of British monarch coronations. 
                            Across the Thames, the London Eye observation wheel provides panoramic views of the South Bank cultural com<br>
                            <span class="more-text-class"> > more </span>
                        </p>

                    </div>
```

Comment: Please add a starting point in code to get a start in solving your problem, see also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: And so far you have tried.... What? This isn't a free programming drop a request site. Developers come here when they have a specific problem and have made an attempt to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this code it may help you

```js
$(".about-style img").click(function(){
 $(this).hide();
 $("div.about-style").addClass("DivWithScroll");;
});
```

```css
.about-style img{
  position : absolute;
  top : 0;
}

.DivWithScroll{
    height:150px;
    overflow:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    padding : 10px;
    border : 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="about-style">
  <h2 class="about-header">About</h2>
  <p class="about-text-style">
    London, England’s capital, set on the River Thames, is a 21st-century city with history stretching back to Roman times. At its centre stand the imposing Houses of Parliament, the iconic ‘Big Ben’ clock tower and Westminster Abbey, site of British monarch coronations. 
    Across the Thames, the London Eye observation wheel provides panoramic views of the South Bank cultural complex, and the entire city. times. At its centre stand the imposing Houses of Parliament, the iconic ‘Big Ben’ clock tower and Westminster Abbey, site of British monarch coronations. 
    Across the Thames, the London Eye observation wheel provides panoramic views of the South Bank cultural com
    <span class="more-text-class"> <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i> more </span>
  </p>
  <img src="http://bluemarlinpools.com/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/images/pool-background.png" width="100%" height="210px"/>
</div>
```